# How can I display my heart rate on an Apple Watch face?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I would like the ability to view my heart rate by quickly glancing at my Apple Watch. I know I can use complications to view my activity rings or add a shortcut to the Heart Rate app from my [watch face](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205536), but I couldn't find an option to directly show my heart rate.

Is it possible to display my current heart rate on the Apple Watch face screen?

Comment: Have you looked at [Cardiogram](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cardiogram-for-apple-watch/id1000017994?mt=8)?  It's a free App.  You can set a complication on your watch face that displays your heart rate.